# Pallet without FRAME

Tags: frame

In the [Polkadot Blockchain Academy book](https://polkadot-blockchain-academy.github.io/pba-book/frame/intro/page.html) it is mentioned that FRAME facilitates and accelerates the development of pallets:

> Without FRAME: 2210 lines of code. With FRAME: 310 lines of code.

Undoubtedly, for those who have already developed with FRAME, the process is easier due to their experience in overcoming difficulties and addressing various issues over the past five years. However, for those aiming to deliver pallets today without an understanding of FRAME's complete history, comprehending FRAME itself might be more challenging. My question is, do you happen to know any up-to-date examples of pallets written without FRAME? In real life, I don't believe in shortcuts, and I think it could be helpful to examine a basic pallet developed without FRAME.

Answer (score 1):

This is a philosophical question, I believe.

For instance, in Rust, the `for` loop is frequently used. But do you truly understand what occurs behind the scenes of the `for`? It's essentially a type of shortcut.

Regarding Substrate, it aids in rapid blockchain development without requiring extensive knowledge of consensus and P2P protocols.

Through this shortcut, individuals can quickly engage in this field. If they encounter issues within a specific area, they will begin to delve deeper into it. Requiring people to learn every detail from the start isn't an effective approach.

If you want to understand what happens behind the scenes of a macro, you can use [`cargo-expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) to expand the macro and examine the actual code.

Comment: The question lacks any philosophical aspect. I simply have never encountered a pallet without FRAME, and I am curious about what exactly constitutes FRAME.

Comment: I just experiment with cargo-expand, thanks for the comment!